# Find the maximum number in a matrix that is less than another number

Tags: matlab, scripting

Say I have a matrix X, and I want to get the row and column numbers of the maximum value in X that is smaller than a number y. How should I go about doing this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5):

This is one way to do it

```
X = rand(4,4)
y = rand
f = X - y;
f(f > 0) = -inf;
[~, ind] = max(f(:));
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(X), ind)
```